# Joomla - get images from directory

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I am trying to get a list of paths for all images in a directory. I am using Joomla 2.5 and was wondering if there are some nice API calls that will assist. I know how to code this up in pure PHP, but would rather use built in Joomla! methods - if they exist.

I have had a poke around in the joomla! libraries, but haven't come across much. I was expecting to see some methods in media manager for this, but couldn't see any. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Joomla way to do this is the following:

```
JFolder::files($path, $filter = '.', $recurse, $fullpath , $exclude);
```

When setting `$recurse` to true, also subfolders will be searched. `$fullpath` set to true returns the full path in the array. With `$exclude`, you can offer an array of extensions, not to include in the search for files. It returns an array with all filenames.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for. I actually did look in JFolder for a method. Must have been half asleep. Thanks for the help.